# How to pass items into picker component?

Tags: react-native

I have a picker component,I want to pass option items as an array into picker component and options should be visible in the picker.

**pickerComonent.js**

```
 <Picker
      mode="dropdown"
      style={styles.picker}
      selectedValue={this.state.language}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
        this.setState({ language: itemValue })
      }
    >
      {options.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Picker.Item label={item.language} value={index} key={index} />
        );
      })}

    </Picker>


PickerInputForm.PropTypes = {
 options: PropTypes.array.isRequired
 };
```

**Home.js**

```
let options = [
   { id: 1, language: 'english' },
   {
     id: 2,
   language: 'Malayalam'
   }
 ];

<PickerInputForm options={options} />
```

When  compiling getting error message "cant find variable options".

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.props.options.map` instead of `options.map` in **pickerComonent.js**

Comment: Error "undefined" is not an object.